# Can I fill 2 dimension-array without using loop in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, we can fill 1 dimensional Integer array with using

```
Arrays.fill(arr, -1);
```

Is there any way to fill 2 or 3 dimensional Integer array without using loop?
With using 1 loop or 2 loop I can. But I want to know how can I fill without using this.

Comment: why do you want to do this? Anyway `Arrays.fill()` is using simple `for` loop so you will get no performance boost here. Just create your own method

Comment: In fact `Arrays#fill` also uses a loop internally. So you never fill an array without a loop.

Comment: If you are going to fill a multi-dimensional array, you are not going to have a sparse or triangular array anyway, so you could just use a one-dimensional array instead and fiddle with the indexes a bit to make it look multi-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I know that Arrays.fill use simple for loop.
but i just want to know if there is any way to fill without "showing loop" which means that be shown on the code.

Comment: This is silly. But you can replace loops with recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Arrays.fill(row, -1);
Arrays.fill(arr, row);
```

you should get:

```
[
 [-1,-1,-1],
 [-1,-1,-1],
 [-1,-1,-1]
]
```

Complete example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Fill {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] row = new int[5];
        int[][] arr = new int[5][];
        Arrays.fill(row, -1);
        Arrays.fill(arr, row);

        for (int[] r : arr) {
            for (int c : r) {
                System.out.print(c + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

**Please note, this way, you'll get an array of references to the same initial array**

Comment: But that will put the same single row into every column. Meaning if you change one element, it will update in lots of different places.

Comment: That's what was asked - how to fill an array with the same value `Is there any way to fill 2 or 3 dimensional Integer array without using loop?`

Comment: yes, with the same *values*, not with references to a single shared value.

Comment: @Thilo you are right you'd have an array of references pointing to the same initial array